# Redirect user authenticate form in action using a AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a .Net Web application using ASP MVC, jQuery & AJAX.
I have a list of products, when I click on the detail button of a product , I'm redirected in a details view which contains a button "Add to cart"

This button calls an action this following segment code:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int articleId)
    {
        ViewBag.CartCount = 0;
        List<Cart> cart = null;

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Session["Cart"] == null)
            {
                cart = new List<Cart>();
                cart.Add(new Cart { ArticleId = articleId, Count = 1, DateCreated = DateTime.Now });
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            else
            {
                cart = Session["Cart"] as List<Cart>;
                var alreadyOrdered = cart.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArticleId == articleId);
                cart.Remove(alreadyOrdered);

                if (alreadyOrdered != null)
                {
                    alreadyOrdered.Count++;
                    cart.Add(alreadyOrdered);
                }
                else
                {
                    cart.Add(new Cart { ArticleId = articleId, Count = 1, DateCreated = DateTime.Now });
                }
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            ViewBag.CartCount = cart.Count;
            return Content(cart.Count.ToString());
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

In my view I have the following code:

```
    @model WebShop.Web.ViewModels.ArticleViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff"
             alt="Kodak Brownie Flash B Camera"
             class="image-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>@Model.Label</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span class="label label-default">@Model.CategoryName</span>
                <span class="label label-info">@Model.SubCategoryName</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="description">
                    @Model.Description
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bottom-rule">
                <h2 class="product-price">@Model.Price.ToString("###") €</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row add-to-cart">
            <div class="col-md-5 product-qty">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
                <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty" value="1" />
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-brand btn-full-width addToCart" id="@Model.Id">
                    Ajouter au panier
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bottom-rule top-10"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.addToCart').click(function () {
            var articleId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shopping")',
                data: { articleId: articleId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#CartModal').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

My desire is when I click on the "Add to cart" button and the user is not authenticated he must be redirected to the authentication page (I'm using the ASP template for authentication) and after continue his selection of product.
When the user is already connected, the value must be returned.
In otherwords, I want to redirect the user to the log on page  if he is not authenticated.

How can I handle this scenario ?

Thanks in advance for your help (it's my first post in StackOverFlow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a json response from your action method and in your ajax call check this data and determine what to do  (redirect to login page or some other page or something else)

When everything goes good, you can return a JSON like this

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "cartItemCount":3
}
```

If user is not authenticated, return something like this

```
{
  "status":"notloggedin"
  "redirectUrl":"account/login"
}
```

So your action method code would be something like

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  // set to cart session
   return Json(new { status="success", cartItemCount=cart.Count()});
}
else
{
  var rUrl="url to login action here"; //use UrlHelper to generate this
  return Json(new { status="notloggedin", redirectUrl=redirectUrl });
}
```

Now in your success callback check the status property and redirect as needed

```
success: function (data) {
  if(data.status==="success")
  {
     $('#CartModal').html(data.cartItemCount);
  }
  else if(data.status==="notloggedin")
  {
    window.location.href=data.redirectUrl;
  }
  else
  {
     alert("some error");
  }
}
```

Finally to generate the url's in the action method, you can try this

```
var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var url = urlBuilder.Action("YourAction", "YourController");
```